# Delayed job enqueue problem on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I got an annoying problem on heroku. Local there is no problem, but in Heroku, when I call this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue PdfImageProcessingJob.new(id)
```

I got this error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):

My PdfImageProcessingJob class is kind of:

```
class PdfImageProcessingJob < Struct.new(:pdf_id)
  ...
end
```

The trace are about:

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.19.1/lib/heroku/client.rb:52:in `info'
/app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/manager/heroku.rb:14:in `qty'
/app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/manager.rb:20:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/job.rb:272:in `after_create'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_create_callbacks' 
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `create'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:246:in `create_or_update'
```

Which is strange, cos the app is in the

> bamboo-mri-1.9.2

stack.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

Where I manage workers, I got a client:

```
@client = ::Heroku::Client.new(username, password)
```

And with this client at enqueue I call

```
@client.info(@app)
```

So there is no error handling, and I called that with nil (An environment variable was missing).

Thats it.

Comment: I found this page after having a similar error re: "rake aborted! undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass)"  In case anyone else comes in from the same angle I did, my solution was to change the HireFire configuration variable like so:  "config.environment = :local" for development or ":heroku" for production.